# Segmentation fault while copying a string to the memory allocated array

Tags: arrays, c, string, malloc

Following is a program I am practicing;

```
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    char **grid = (char **) malloc(5*sizeof(int));
        for (i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
            grid[i] = (char *) malloc(6);
            strcpy(grid[0], "eabcd");
            strcpy(grid[1], "fghij");
            strcpy(grid[2], "olkmn");
            strcpy(grid[3], "trpqs");
            strcpy(grid[4], "xywuv"); /*Segmentation Fault at this line*/
        return 0;
}
```

I am getting a segmentation fault at the line  `strcpy(grid[4], "xywuv");` . What could be the reason? I have allocated the array to have 5 strings(rows) of 6 characters each(columns).

Comment: `5*sizeof(int)` - why `int`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are allocating the wrong type at line 3

`char **grid = (char **) malloc(5*sizeof(int));`

Should be
`char **grid = (char **) malloc(5*sizeof(char*));`

This is because you are declaring string-array. Therefore, the malloc should be `char* (string / character pointer)`

Also the same if you were trying to declare 2-D integer array. It will be

`int **grid = (int **) malloc(5*sizeof(int*));`